# Teaching analogy question

Tags: discussion

As of this writing, three people have flagged [this question](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/6127/what-are-some-real-life-applications-of-the-knapsack-problems-class) for closure.  However, I believe that it is a straightforward [teaching-analogy](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching-analogy) question, well in line with past examples.  Here are just a few that seem similar to the question being flagged:

- [A real world example for the divide and conquer method](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/5826/a-real-world-example-for-the-divide-and-conquer-method)
- [Physical analogy to introduce a Delegate in .Net programming](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/3675/physical-analogy-to-introduce-a-delegate-in-net-programming)
- [How do I explain blockchain using an analogy?](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/2800/how-do-i-explain-blockchain-using-an-analogy)
- [What is a good analogy to introduce databases and SQL?](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/1419/what-is-a-good-analogy-to-introduce-databases-and-sql)
- [What are some good examples of using a stack data structure?](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/791/what-are-some-good-examples-of-using-a-stack-data-structure)
- [Intuitive example of an NP problem](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/727/intuitive-example-of-an-np-problem)
- [What is a good analogy for pass by value vs by reference?](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/583/what-is-a-good-analogy-for-pass-by-value-vs-by-reference)
- [What are some good real-life examples of pipelining, latency, and throughput?](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/3092/what-are-some-good-real-life-examples-of-pipelining-latency-and-throughput)

From the tag description:

> Questions looking for analogies with which to teach computer science principles or concepts, or questions discussing specific teaching analogies for such computer science principles or concepts. Metaphors used in teaching is also an appropriate topic here.

The only thing that I notice about the question is that it doesn't mention a student level, which is also per the tag description:

> So analogies are also somewhat specific to the level of the students in question (high-school, university etc.).

While the lack of a level certainly weakens the question, I don't see why this would rise to the level of closure.  I believe that we should leave the question open, though seeing three closure flags makes me wonder if I have missed something, so I have come to the community to ask: does this question differ from the examples above, and if so, what would have to be updated in the document to make the acceptable standards clearer?

Comment: I guess if you want questions on the site, you should be welcoming and supportive, rather than voting to close. This is the biggest problem I have seen with SE: people are legalistic instead of encouraging. You catch more flies with honey than with vinegar, although a big Catcher's mitt can be handy too. And let's not forget the rye.

Comment: That was *you* as in 'ya' - the 4th person indefinite. Not 'you' Ben. Just to clarify, because *you* and *ya* are often mistaken.